# Cannot select Image File using djangocms-filer

Tags: django, django-cms, djangocms-text-ckeditor

I hope someone can help out with this one.  I have been using djangocms to build a simple frontend centric website for a client so they can maintain their own content.  There is nothing fancy in this setup.  Just a few template.html files, a little css and djangocms to pull it all together.  There are no other forms, models, views or anything at this stage.  Just pure djangocms.

Originally I was working with django 1.8.6 and the image picker seemed to work fine.  I could upload my files and next to each one there is a selector icon which works and all was great.  See below image. This was using cmsplugin-filer.

[image]

Then I tried to upgrade the website to Django version 1.11.13 and I started to run into this problem.  The file select that you see above is no longer available to the user. I have spent days working on this and in my travels I found that apparently cmsplugin-filer is now deprecated.  So I removed it and switched to the recommended djangocms-filer install thinking that might solve my problem...but no.  After many many hours of head scratching I figured it must be something in my project throwing things out, so I have done a 100% clean install using the prescribed djangocms-installer.  Other than connecting it to a postgresql database, it is a completely vanilla installation, and yet it still does not work.  All I get is the image below.  A simple tick box but no way of selecting the image nor anyway of saving what I have selected. Uploading files is fine and I can create folders and images upload into them perfectly fine.

[image]

Below is a snapshot of my pip freeze showing everything installed in my virtualenv and the associated versions.

[image]

My settings file is almost 100% standard so I don't understand why I can't get this to work.  Note: If, when I am adding the plugin to my template, I don't select the Choose File Button but simply drag an image into the grey rectangle, it all works fine.  My file gets uploaded into the unsorted uploads folder and the image is selected into my template all in one go, but using the choose file route, where I have more control over my files and how they are stored, doesn't.

Does anyone have any idea what I might be missing please?

UPDATE:
[image]

Comment: What happens when you select the images? Does it just open the change form for the images? I'm sure when I've tried to use filer I found that after uploading images I couldn't then select them to include them in anything, I just kept getting the change form.

Comment: Hi Mark, I just get the Django Admin file manager type window, where I can see all my images and upload plenty more, make folders etc etc.  I can even tick the box next to an image, I just can't then send the selection back to the page.  There is a cancel button in the bottom right corner but no save or continue button or anything like that.  See new image posted above.

Comment: Same issue happens to me today, have you found some solution @cander

Comment: Hey Alleo, no I didn't. I kind of shelved the issue for a while and when I came back to it, it was all working fine.  It may be there was some update somewhere along the line but as I had parked it for several months, I can't give you a definitive answer as to what the solution is. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Django CMS overrides some static files and there are some old ones in your browser cache. You need to clear your caches or open the page using incognito window.